# Celery not picking up task from queue on ECS

Tags: django, celery, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using celery in my Django application together with rabbitmq to perform heavy long running tasks. I created ECS services on AWS and for celery worker service I enabled autoscaling. I created an alert on Cloudwatch to create new container when new message appears in queue. I chose message count
VirtualHost celery queue because that's where all my messages are going to.

The problem I am facing is that  celery does not pick up the task from the queue even if new container in service is created. I checked rabbimq admin panel and I see new messages and I see that new containes are added but celery is not picking them up. I set up concurrency to 2 and 2 tasks are running properly but the next ones are starting only if any of these 2 tasks are completed.

I tried to use --autoscale=15,2 option and I added -Q celery to specify the queue name. It is working but when I tried to run more than 15 tasks simultaneously I have the same problem so containers are created but tasks are not picked up from the queue.

What I want to achieve is that new containers in a service are added and celery is picking up the task automatically from the queue.